# how to call url of any other website in php

Tags: php

how to call url of any other website in php.

Comment: can u add more details ?

Comment: Actually i hv to write web service. now in this i want to call the url whose API's i am going to use in code

Comment: when i use curl it gives fatal error As: Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample.php on line 3

Comment: @Beginner, please elaborate. By `elaborate` we mean show us some of the code in question so that we can actually help instead of guess :)

Comment: <?php
$cURL = curl_init();


curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");


curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


$strPage = curl_exec($cURL);


curl_close($cURL);


echo($strPage);

?>
Error for this is:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample.php on line 3

Answer (score 66, accepted):

use curl php library: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

direct example: [CURL_EXEC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php):

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: when i use curl it gives fatal error
As:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample.php on line 3

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? Is it compiled with curl? try phpinfo();

Comment: i am using XAMPP 1.7.3 i thing it contents PHP version 5.3.1

Comment: uncomment (remove ;) the line ;extension=php_curl.dll in php.ini

Comment: i dowmload curl library then also i am getting same problem.
Is it necessary that we hv to store this library in specific folder

Comment: @Andy i am not getting this line in php.ini
extension=php_curl.dll

Comment: thanks, to all of you. its working now, when i make changes in php.ini file

Comment: how to get the response from that URL??

Comment: @JayPatel simply store the response of `curl_exec($ch);` in a variable like so `$data = curl_exec($ch);` now you have the whole content of your target url in `$data`

Answer (score 33):

As other's have mentioned, PHP's cURL functions will allow you to perform advanced HTTP requests.  You can also use [`file_get_contents`](http://uk.php.net/file_get_contents) to access REST APIs:

```
$payload = file_get_contents('http://api.someservice.com/SomeMethod?param=value');
```

Starting with PHP 5 you can also [create a stream context](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) which will allow you to change headers or post data to the service.

Comment: Note that this increases the execution time as the entire HTML file is read into the PHP buffer. If more than 30 seconds, your script might stop to work. Then you might want to use `set_time_limit(600)` or better use cURL instead.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way would be to use FOpen or one of FOpen's Wrappers.

```
$page = file_get_contents("http://www.domain.com/filename");
```

This does require FOpen which some web hosts disable and some web hosts will allow FOpen, but not allow access to external files. You may want to check where you are going to run the script to see if you have access to External FOpen.

Answer (score 5):

If you meant .. to *REDIRECT* from that page to another, the function is really simple

```
header("Location:www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) functions. They should do what you want.

Or if you just want a simple URL GET then:

```
$lines = file('http://www.example.com/');
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean, either [redirect](http://php.net/redirect) or use [curl](http://php.net/curl).