# How to make call HTTPS url from php code?

Tags: php, http

I have a HTTPS URL containing some data in the form of parameter like below:

```
https://api.afterbuy.de/afterbuy/ShopInterface.aspx?Action=new&Lieferanschrift=0&Partnerid=102618&KLFirma=&PartnerPass=(mcYTtxxUYpfUNAExiXVRReQ8&KLVorname=&UserID=deubagmbh&KLNachname=&PosAnz=2&KLStrasse=&KLStrasse2=&Kbenutzername=Mustertester&KLPLZ=&KPLZ=add12&Kanrede=&KLOrt=&KFirma=&KLLand=count12&KVorname=masoom&KLBundesland=&Artikelnr_1=...............
```

It is functioning from browser direct hit and giving me response.

But I want a PHP code through which I can make a call to the above URL and get response.

Please suggest me how i can be achieve in PHP. I am a Java programmer. I am new in PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call url of any other website in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446654/how-to-call-url-of-any-other-website-in-php)

Comment: `file_get_contents` should work fine, make sure you have an `SSL` module enabled.

Comment: Thanks Frits, `file_get_contents` method has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.http.php

Here is an example from php.net:

```
<?php
$response = http_get("http://www.example.com/", array("timeout"=>1), $info);
print_r($info);
?>
```