# exec () php function not working

Tags: php

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    session_start();
    function code($no_of_char)
        {
            $code='';
            $possible_char="0123456789";
            while($no_of_char>0)
                {
                    $code.=substr($possible_char, rand(0, strlen($possible_char)-1), 1);
                    $no_of_char--;
                }
            return $code;
        }

        function sendSms($msg, $to)
        {

        $to=trim($to);
        $m.=urlencode($msg);

   $smsurl="http://bhashsms.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=*****&pass=*****&sender=******&phone=$to&text=$m&priority=ndnd&stype=normal";

    $return = exec($smsurl);
        return $return;
        }

    ?>
```

`print_r($smsurl)` is showing absolutely right command which i want but doesn't executing `exec($smsurl)`
i m not familiar with `exec()` function.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any error you are getting?

Comment: Are you trying something like which is answered here? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446654/how-to-call-url-of-any-other-website-in-php

Comment: Using `exec(some url)` does **NOTHING**. it's like print url in your console. Anything happens? Nope. So what do you expect?

Comment: i expect the url should work for me

Comment: The url is not a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

exec is used for executing an external program but accessing some webpage/api from a web url is not a valid use case for exec. Try this if you want to get data from an Url.

[how to call url of any other website in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446654/how-to-call-url-of-any-other-website-in-php)

Comment: there is another problem after successful sending otp via sms is sending delivery report and location: fuction stops and i can't move the other php page

Comment: Can you be more elaborate? What is otp? and what about sending delivery report and location. And what function stops

Comment: otp means one time password which i sent to users using sms gateway
and after sending otp ,user can redirect on verification.php page but after successfull deliver otp to users mobile a delivery report came from sms gateway and my php scripts stops on register page and cannot work header("location:verification.php");

Comment: Firstly dont use some echo after the command header("location:verification.php");

Secondly i ll need to see some code so I can debug or tell you some specific.